# How do I test bootstrap-vue toasts

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I have been instructed to assert that our errors have been surfaced in bootstrap-vue toasts. How can I assert that the toast has been made on my tests.  I was hoping to mock out ‘this.$bvToast.toast’ however I have been unable to find anything salient so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem and the way I solved it was to wrap the `this.$bvToast.toast()` around a component method `showToast()`:

```
// component

{
   ...
   showToast(title: string, content: string) {
      this.$bvToast.toast(
         content,
         {
            title,
            ...
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Then, in my jest file I just use a spy and make sure the parameters are the ones I expect

```
// component.spec

const mySpy = jest.spyOn(myComponent, 'showToast');
...
your code here
...
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedTitle, expectedContent)
```

Of course, this doesn't test the actual text inside the bootstrap-vue toast component, but this defeats also the purpose of the unit test: you assume that the toast works as it should :)

Comment: That's tidy!

Since then, we've moved on to using @testing-library/vue